# Where can I see previous Make It Happen campaigns?

Tags: fundraising, crowd-funding

Where can I see funded and / or implemented Make It Happen campaigns?

On the page https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen I can only see the ones that are currently being fundraised for.

Comment: There's a discussion going on in chat.civicrm.org in the infrastructure channel about this. You can join in there.